# How to correctly write a ruby method

Tags: ruby

i'm trying ruby. I want to make a program which can continue the sequence.

> 1
>
> 11
>
> 21
>
> 1211
>
> 111221

(which next line is a calculated each number of previous line)
For example last line is(see previous) one of 1, one of 2, and two of 1.
I make a code and it works fine:

```
5.times do
result_seq = []
count = 1
puts initial_seq.join
initial_seq.size.times do
  if (value = initial_seq.shift) == initial_seq.first
    count += 1
  else
    result_seq << count << value
    count = 1
  end
end
initial_seq = result_seq
end
```

But now I want to write a simple method called **Next**

I want to make:

```
sec = Sequence.new(1)
sec.next -> will return 11
sec.next.next -> will return 21
sec.next.next.next -> will return 1211
```

How can i write it correctly using my code?

UPD

I wrote the tests for it:

```
require "spec_helper"

require "sequence"

describe Sequence do
  let(:sequence) { Sequence.new("1") }

  describe "to_s" do
    it "return initial value" do
      expect(sequence.to_s).to eql "1"
    end
  end

  describe "next" do
    it "generate next state" do
      expect(sequence.next.to_s).to eql "11"
    end

    it "return Sequence instance" do
      expect(sequence.next).to be_an_instance_of(Sequence)
    end

    it "generate next state 2 times" do
      expect(sequence.next.next.to_s).to eql "21"
    end

    it "generate next state 3 times" do
      expect(sequence.next.next.next.to_s).to eql "1211"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not follow the logic behind the desired output. `which next line is a calculated each number of previous line` - what does that mean?..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko look at code, maybe it will help to understand the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Sequence
  attr_reader :initial_seq

  def initialize(initial_seq = [])
    @initial_seq = initial_seq
    print_next
  end

  def print_next
    result_seq = []
    count = 1
    puts initial_seq.join
    initial_seq.size.times do
      if (value = initial_seq.shift) == initial_seq.first
        count += 1
      else
        result_seq << count << value
        count = 1
      end
    end
    @initial_seq = result_seq
    self #<===== The most important part for being able to chain `print_next`
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
Sequence.new([1]).print_next.print_next.print_next.print_next
1
11
21
1211
111221
```

## edit

If you want to initialize it with integer argument, not array:

```
def initialize(number)
  @initial_seq = [number]
  print_next
end

Sequence.new(1).print_next.print_next
1
11
21
```

Or, if you do not want `initialize` to accept an argument (assuming, it will always start with `1`):

```
def initialize
  @initial_seq = [1]
  print_next
end


Sequence.new.print_next.print_next
1
11
21
```

Comment: Can u help me, to initialize without an array?
Just like def initialize(value). It is static and always 1.
I want to conctructor like Sequence.new(1) (without a array in conctrucor)

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev sure, it's even easier then, let me edit the answer

Comment: Check my UPD pls, i wrote a tests, can u test your code with it? i'll tried to test your code, everything wrong

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev  I did not change your code, it produces the same result as it does in your question (copy/paste it now and run your test)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby provides Enumerators, which behave almost like in OP. Leaving the original code almost unaltered:

```
seq = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  initial_seq = [1]

  loop do  #endless loop, but don't worry, its lazy
    result_seq = []
    count = 1
    yielder << initial_seq.join
    initial_seq.size.times do
      if (value = initial_seq.shift) == initial_seq.first
        count += 1
      else
        result_seq << count << value
        count = 1
      end
    end
    initial_seq = result_seq
  end
end

5.times{puts seq.next}
puts seq.next
```